# c#: Call boxed delegate

Tags: c#, reflection, delegates

In my project I need to transform data between several classes so I created a class DataMapper that is used for strong-typed mapping of properties from two different classes. When properties in the pair need to be modified I store two delegates (converters) for this purpose.

Then the DataMapper has two methods Update(T source, S target) and Update(S source, T target) that use these mappings to provide the tranformation.

```
public class DataMapper<TSourceType, TTargetType> : IDataUpdater<TSourceType, TTargetType> {

    private readonly IDictionary<PropertyInfo, PropertyInfo> _sourceToTargetMap = new Dictionary<PropertyInfo, PropertyInfo>();
    private readonly IDictionary<PropertyInfo, object> _converters = new Dictionary<PropertyInfo, object>();

    public DataMapper<TSourceType, TTargetType> Map<TSourceValue, TTargetValue>(
        Expression<Func<TSourceType, TSourceValue>> sourcePropExpr,
        Expression<Func<TTargetType, TTargetValue>> targetPropExpr) 
    {
        _sourceToTargetMap.Add(sourcePropExpr.AsPropertyInfo(), targetPropExpr.AsPropertyInfo());
        return this;
    }

    public DataMapper<TSourceType, TTargetType> Map<TSourceValue, TTargetValue>(
        Expression<Func<TSourceType, TSourceValue>> sourcePropExpr,
        Expression<Func<TTargetType, TTargetValue>> targetPropExpr,
        Func<TSourceValue, TTargetValue> sourceToTargetConverter, 
        Func<TTargetValue, TSourceValue> targetToSourceConverter) 
    {
        _sourceToTargetMap.Add(sourcePropExpr.AsPropertyInfo(), targetPropExpr.AsPropertyInfo());
        _converters.Add(sourcePropExpr.AsPropertyInfo(), sourceToTargetConverter);
        _converters.Add(targetPropExpr.AsPropertyInfo(), targetToSourceConverter);
        return this;
    }

    public void Update(TSourceType source, TTargetType target) {
        foreach (var keyValuePair in _sourceToTargetMap) {
            var sourceProp = keyValuePair.Key;
            var targetProp = keyValuePair.Value;
            Update(source, target, sourceProp, targetProp);
        }
    }

    public void Update(TTargetType source, TSourceType target) {
        foreach (var keyValuePair in _sourceToTargetMap) {
            var sourceProp = keyValuePair.Value;
            var targetProp = keyValuePair.Key;
            Update(source, target, sourceProp, targetProp);
        }
    }

    private void Update(
        object source, 
        object target, 
        PropertyInfo sourceProperty, 
        PropertyInfo targetProperty) 
    {
        var sourceValue = sourceProperty.GetValue(source);
        if (_converters.ContainsKey(sourceProperty)) {
            sourceValue = typeof(InvokeHelper<,>)
                .MakeGenericType(sourceProperty.PropertyType, targetProperty.PropertyType)
                .InvokeMember("Call", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, null, new[] { _converters[sourceProperty], sourceValue });
        }
        targetProperty.SetValue(target, sourceValue);
    }
}
```

Here is the usage:

```
public SomeClass {
    private static readonly IDataUpdater<SomeClass, SomeOtherClass> _dataMapper = new DataMapper<SomeClass, SomeOtherClass>()
        .Map(x => x.PropertyA, y => y.PropertyAA)
        .Map(x => x.PropertyB, y => y.PropertyBB, x => Helper.Encrypt(x), y => Helper.Decrypt(y));

    public string PropertyA { get; set; }
    public string PropertyB { get; set; }

    public void LoadFrom(SomeOtherClass source) {
        _dataMapper.Update(source, this);
    }

    public void SaveTo(SomeOtherClass target) {
        _dataMapper.Update(this, target);
    }
}
```

You can see in class DataHelper in the last overload of method Update that when I want to call the stored converter function, I use helper class InvokeHelper, because I didn't found other way how to call boxed delegate Func. Code for class InvokeHelper is simple - just single static method:

```
public static class InvokeHelper<TSource, TTarget> {
    public static TTarget Call(Func<TSource, TTarget> converter, TSource source) {
        return converter(source);
    }
}
```

Is there a way how to do it without reflection? I need to optimalize these transformations for speed.

Thanks.

Comment: Note that delegates are reference types, not value types, and so cannot be boxed.

Comment: You shouldn't be walking the entire dictoinary and doing a linear search to find the values; it's defeating the entire purpose of using a dictionary.  You should be actually leveraging its ability to find a value for a particular key *without needing to do any of that*.

Comment: Servy: ok I wrrote "boxed delegate" but I ment delegate persisted as object (in dictionary _converters)
PS: I dont understand your second comment about walking entire dictionary

Comment: You're doing a linear search through the dictionary, looking at every single object, instead of looking up the value for a key, which doesn't require looking at most objects.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Delegate.DynamicInvoke` to invoke the delegate. Or, use `dynamic`:

```
((dynamic)(Delegate)_converters[sourceProperty])(sourceValue);
```

The `(Delegate)` cast is not necessary. It's for documentation and runtime assertion purposes. Leave it out if you don't like it.

Actually, you better use `delegate` instead of `object` in the dictionary.

Comment: Well thanks, that's it ... when I just persist Delegate instead of object into dictionary _converterters I can call DynamicInvoke on its values.

Answer (score 0):

If it were me, I would use a little meta-coding with expressions to create a list of compiled and strongly typed delegates.  When you call the `Update` method, you can go through each `Action` in the list and update the destination from the source.

No reflection and all of the compiling and such is done once, ahead of the Update call.

```
public class DataMapper<TSourceType, TTargetType> : IDataUpdater<TSourceType, TTargetType>
{
    List<Action<TSourceType, TTargetType>> _mappers = new List<Action<TSourceType, TTargetType>>();
    DataMapper<TTargetType, TSourceType> _reverseMapper;

    public DataMapper() : this(false) { }
    public DataMapper(bool isReverse)
    {
        if (!isReverse)
        {
            _reverseMapper = new DataMapper<TTargetType, TSourceType>(isReverse: true);
        }
    }

    public DataMapper<TSourceType, TTargetType> Map<TSourceValue, TTargetValue>(
        Expression<Func<TSourceType, TSourceValue>> sourcePropExpr,
        Expression<Func<TTargetType, TTargetValue>> targetPropExpr)
    {
        var mapExpression = Expression.Assign(targetPropExpr.Body, sourcePropExpr.Body);

        _mappers.Add(
            Expression.Lambda<Action<TSourceType, TTargetType>>(
                mapExpression,
                sourcePropExpr.Parameters[0],
                targetPropExpr.Parameters[0])
            .Compile());

        if (_reverseMapper != null) _reverseMapper.Map(targetPropExpr, sourcePropExpr);

        return this;
    }

    public DataMapper<TSourceType, TTargetType> Map<TSourceValue, TTargetValue>(
        Expression<Func<TSourceType, TSourceValue>> sourcePropExpr,
        Expression<Func<TTargetType, TTargetValue>> targetPropExpr,
        Func<TSourceValue, TTargetValue> sourceToTargetConverter,
        Func<TTargetValue, TSourceValue> targetToSourceConverter)
    {
        var convertedSourceExpression = Expression.Invoke(Expression.Constant(sourceToTargetConverter), sourcePropExpr.Body);
        var mapExpression = Expression.Assign(targetPropExpr.Body, convertedSourceExpression);

        _mappers.Add(
            Expression.Lambda<Action<TSourceType, TTargetType>>(
                mapExpression,
                sourcePropExpr.Parameters[0],
                targetPropExpr.Parameters[0])
            .Compile());

        if (_reverseMapper != null) _reverseMapper.Map(targetPropExpr, sourcePropExpr, targetToSourceConverter, sourceToTargetConverter);
        return this;
    }

    public void Update(TSourceType source, TTargetType target)
    {
        foreach (var mapper in _mappers)
        {
            mapper(source, target);
        }
    }

    public void Update(TTargetType source, TSourceType target)
    {
        if (_reverseMapper != null)
        {
            _reverseMapper.Update(source, target);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Reverse mapper is null.  Did you reverse twice?");
        };
    }
}
```

The expression is built by taking the expressions that are passed in and using them as parts for the new expression.

Say you called `.Map(x => x.PropertyA, y => y.PropertyAA)`.  You now have 2 expressions each with a parameter `x` and `y` and each with a body `x.PropertyA` and `y.PropertyAA`.

Now you want to re-assemble these expression parts into an assignment expression like `y.PropertyAA = x.PropertyA`.  This is done in the line `var mapExpression = Expression.Assign(targetPropExpr.Body, sourcePropExpr.Body);` which gives you an expected expression.

Now when you call Expression.Lambda, you are incorporating the parameters (`x`,`y`) into a new expression that looks like `(x,y) = > y.PropertyAA = x.PropertyA`.

Before you can execute this, you need to compile it, hence the `.Compile()`.  But since you only need to compile this once for any given map, you can compile and store the result.  The uncompiled expression is of type `Expression<Action<TSourceType,TTargetType>>` and after it is compiled the resulting type is `Action<TSourceType,TTargetType>`

Comment: Hi Grax, thanks for your answer. I'll try this solution ... now it looks to me a little bit complicated because I don't know much about creating Lambda Expressions, but I'll try to immerse into it.

Comment: Understood, I added more detail about how the expression building is working.  Hopefully that helps.